# Function firing at same time by trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I created trigger in PostgreSQL which may fires multiple time in a single moment.
This trigger is calling another function to insert data in table(s).
There is a select statement to find the **id** (by returning statement and save in a variable) of respective record from tabl say  **TableA** and then i have to insert multiple rows in other table say **TableB** referencing this **id** .

My issue is: this variable holding **Id**,  sometimes insert wrong value in **TableB** .
what i understand (may be wrong) , this variable value changes during the insertion (at same time trigger fires again).

like

```
declare Id integer;
select keyID INTO Id from tableA;
INSERT INTO TableB (Id, date) values (Id, now());
```

Could any one please explain, what exactly the issue in this case.
Will be thankful if provide solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger is running in the same transaction as the statement that triggered it, and it cannot see the effects of other transactions that are currently running (no “dirty reads”).

So if two data modifying statements are running at the same time, the concurrently running trigger functions cannot “see” the modifications by the other transaction, and you can end up with a result that could never have happened if the operations had been executed one after the other. This is called an *anomaly*.

The default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level cannot protect you from such anomalies, nor can `REPEATABLE READ`. Only if all transactions are using the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, no anomalies can occur. In this case, one of the transactions will be aborted by a *serialization error* and has to be repeated.

An alternative approach is to lock rows as you read them by using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. Then you can use `READ COMMITTED` isolation, but the locks will be bad for concurrency and can lead to deadlocks, which also lead to the termination of one of the involved transactions.

Comment: Thank dear, By your help, i just divert my concentration to other code, and i found that we are doing a blunder in written script which fires same function in some special cases for that, it inserts duplicate/wrong references in the table... Moreover your above help is very useful and make my other concepts right.... :)